# Form is not submitting to database

Tags: php, html

So after I enter the information on my form it refreshes the new.php page with a new form but doesn't submit any information. I get no errors its just like I clicked refresh on the page. I feel like i've done everything right but I just can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I've just transitioned from mysql to mysqli so I'm kinda a noob with it. It's also not routing back to home.php.

**new.php**

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('config/db.php'); ?>




<div id="newform">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user">User</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="Username"> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rank">Rank</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="rank">
                <option value="1">Noob</option>
                <option value="2">Semi-Noob</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="<?php echo date('d M y'); ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tag">Tag</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tag" placeholder="Tag">
        </div>      
        <center>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </center>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//Values to be inserted into the DB
$user = $_POST['user'];
$rank = $_POST['rank'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$tag  = $_POST['tag'];

//Preparing the statement
$query = "INSERT INTO players (user, rank, date, tag) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

//Binding Parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double, b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('siss', $user, $rank, $date, $tag);

//Execution
if($statement->execute()){
    header('Location: home.php');
}else{
    die('Error : ('.$mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
$statement->close();
}
?>

<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: many issues, a few being that forms default to GET if POST isn't used. Then your conditional statement. `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` use error reporting. Here's another `(user, rank, date, tag) VALUES(?, ?, ?)` once you get past the first gauntlet.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry if i may sound like an idiot but i am not really understanding your reply too much. I've been using POST  and i have error reporting setup

Comment: @Riley - he means that if you don't have a method of `post` in your form, it'll use `get` by default, meaning that none of the `$_POST` variables will be set. And your insert statement has four columns in the list fields, but you're only giving three values)

Comment: Instead of $_POST you can use $_REQUEST. Can you post your error? Did you check printing the query?

(user, rank, date, tag) VALUES(?, ?, ?)
4 columns and you have only 3 values`

Comment: @andrewsi Both of those have been fixed and it still does the same thing

Comment: @Riley - The most obvious error remaining that I can see is that you don't have an input named 'submit' in your form, so your if statement will never trigger.

Comment: @PixelMaker No error shows up, and i've fixed the values/columns and they've been updated to my post. All it does is refresh the new.php page with a new form

Comment: use `name` instead of `id` for inputs

Comment: @phplover Thank you, that is what fixed it. Thank you all for the help. I must of had a massive brain fart or something. I'll edit the post accordingly.

Comment: @Riley - you can add an answer to your own question.

Comment: Curious, why did you edit your original question/code to now read as **Fixed & working version**? Future visitors to the question will read comments and ask themselves questions. People will also see the answer below and ask themselves: *"the button's named, so why the answer?"* - Edit: I performed a rollback to the original post. You shouldn't modify your question like that. That's not how Stack rolls ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check after adding  `name="submit"` in  `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Submit</button>
```